sitefinity multisite redirect to main site
I need help with a Sitefinity multisite setup. I added a new site and pointed it to the server, but when I create a page on the multisite and try to view it, it redirects to the main site instead of showing the correct multisite domain.
The multisite is redirecting to the main site instead of displaying its own content. How can I fix this issue?

Not able to reproduce this on 15.1. what's your version?

Sitefinity 14.0.7725.0 DX

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
